# Send value from form in Razor page as parameter in onsubmit method

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, razor, parameter-passing

I am using razor, where I have created a time form to be submitted:

```
<form method="post" @onsubmit="SetTimeWhenHeaterTurnsOn">
  <div>
    <label for="GoalTime">Request a time for the desired temperature</label>
    <input id="GoalTime" type="time" name="appt-time"
           min=@OneHourFromNow required runat="server">
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Set Time">
  </div>
</form>
```

It simply looks like this:

[image: Button]

And I want to pass the value of the time that is set to be used in `SetTimeWhenHeaterTurnsOn`.

I don't really know how to do this though... I tried using `OnPost()` in combination with `Request.Form["appt-time"]` but this doesn't work.

The method I want to use it in currently looks like this:

```
public DateTime GoalTime { get; set; }

public async Task SetTimeWhenHeaterTurnsOn()
        {
            String GoalTimeAsString = GoalTime.ToString("HH:mm");
            Debug.WriteLine($"Time requested: {GoalTimeAsString}");
         }
```

I know I am probably missing something with the `GoalTime` value, or there is perhaps an easier way to get the time value from the form in this method. But I don't know how to.

Currently this prints: `Time requested: 00:00`

I am a beginner in C#, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you using,blazor or razor page？

Comment: Using blazor, with razor pages

Comment: Right now the url is updated with ```?GoalTime=17%3A08``` at the end. But I want the value to be passed to a variable and used in a method parameter.